# Howler.js volume does not change on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, meteor, howler.js

In my Meteor React App I am using a modified version of [React Howler](https://github.com/thangngoc89/react-howler) to play two audio tracks at once (two instances of Howler). I also implemented a simple crossfader to change the audio volume of both tracks at once, which works great in Chrome and on Android. But when I tested it on iOS, I realized it plays the audio just fine but the volume does not change.

The weird thing about this: When I read out the current volume at each time step (the player updates 10 times per second), it outputs the correct values on every platform. This means, volume is being set and stored correctly on iOS but the volume you hear just does not change.

Here's how the volume functions work in my version of ReactHowler:

```
get volume() {
    return this._howler.volume();
}

set volume(val) {
    if(this._howler.volume() != val){
        console.log("setting volume to " + val)
    }
    this._howler.volume(val);
}
```

Console output looks fine, as described earlier. When the crossfader value is changed, it shows

```
setting volume to 0.35
howler volume: 0.35 (this is output at every time frame for debugging purposes)
howler volume: 0.35
...
```

Comment: If you have only one instance of Howler on IOS do volume adjustments work? It may be that either Howler or IOS does not support 2 instances

Comment: Nope, just tested that. Even with one instance the volume is being set but the audio volume stays on the same level. Interestingly, the volume change is instant on Chrome or Android (which uses Chromium), but in Safari on OSX it takes a few seconds after a change until the volume actually differs from the one before, while in Safari on iOS it does not work at all.

Comment: It sounds like the Safari volume change is being done asynchronously, hence the delay. Perhaps on IOS there is some kind of permission problem, ie you didn't tell it that you wanted to modify the volume. And because it's async you don't get an error?

Comment: [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193565/controlling-volume-of-html-audio-element-in-ionic-on-ios) and [This issue on the howler.js github](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/415) seem to describe the same problem.

Comment: They have, however, not found any solutions. I also didn't find a permission that would apply here.

Comment: Now I'm with the same error, only works over android. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered in the [github issue I opened].(https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/805)

This issue occurs when using html5 audio on iOS, disabling this fixes the problem.

Comment: Nope, that doesnt seems to help. disabiling html audio just stops playing the audio itself.